# Physical file (table) performance on IBMi

Tags: ibm-midrange

my customer wants me to produce a report of say top 100 most accessed files (PF) with number of reads/writes/updates.

I did not come to any findings so far.

Is it something for PDI or iDoctor or maybe something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [qsys2.systablestat](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzcatsyststat.htm) view...

```
select table_schema, table_name, system_table_schema, system_table_name 
       , insert_operations, update_operations, delete_operations
from qsys2.systablestat;
```